# Spring Batch can not obtain job lock via DB (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I have several instances of "orchestrator" microservice that runs on different nodes and executes Spring Batch jobs. Only one instance has to be "active" and conduct the job at a time. The jobs are scheduled twice a day via `@Scheduled` annotation with cron expression.
So, mocriservice tries to execute jobs with a single identifying `JobParameter` that is a `LocalDateTime.now()` truncated to seconds to compensate time difference between OpenShift nodes my instances run on.
Underlying DB is Postgres 12, which transaction isolation level is set to **repeatable read**.

The problem seems imossible to me, but it happens and reproduces **always**. **Job execution fails on each microservice instance** with `DuplicateKeyException` on composite PK, which is (not suprisingly) job name and identifying parameter's hash.

The question is how is it possible and what am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: When does this happen exactly? Please share your code and show when the error happens to be able to help you efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a late answer. There were no problem at all, **locks work correctly regardless transaction isolation level**. We have two OpenShift clusters - active and inactive. Jobs were running on "inactive" nodes that are called so just because no client traffic routed to them. As it turned out, production support had no access to "inactive" nodes logs :)